# Packaging a .EXE with the MSI, so that the MSI installs also the exe during msi installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I have to package an 3rd party exe with my MSI.
So ideally the 3rd party exe should get installed first during MSI installation and then it should drop my project dlls.

I'm using a Visual studio setupanddeployment project(2010) - Visual studio installer.
Could someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: When you're talking about "should get installed", do you mean the exe should just be placed in the right location, or do you want to run the exe when the MSI is ran?

Comment: I want to run the exe when the MSI runs.

Answer (score 1):

Add third-party .exe to the project by the same way as any other file. In the File System window initially you have Application Folder, User's Desktop and User's Program Menu. You can place .exe to any of these locations, or create subdolder(s) and place it there. Additionally, you can right-click on File System on Target Machine and add special folder, like Common Files, System etc. To add file, right-click in the right pane and select Add - File.

Comment: I followed exactly what you said but I do not see the thrid party Exe getting installed as part of the MSI installation.